# Implementing MVP correctly in TornadoFX without using inject()

Tags: kotlin, mvp, tornadofx

I want to implement MVP in TornadoFX without using it's inject (because it hurts readability and requires me to depend on something I cannot control).

My idea of good MVP implementation is as follows:

```
interface ModelEventHandler {...}
interface ViewEventHandler {...}
class Model(val eventHandlers: List<ModelEventHandler> = listOf<ModelEventHandler>())
class View(val eventHandlers: List<ViewEventHandler> = listOf<ViewEventHandler>())
class Presenter(val view: View): ModelEventHandler, ViewEventHandler
```

Which can then be used in the following manner:

```
val model = Model()
val view = View()
val presenter = Presenter(view)
model.eventHandlers += presenter
view.eventHandlers += presenter
```

The problem is that with TornadoFX you are forced to let the `App` class do the view initialization for you and you can't pass any parameters, you can't also choose the order in which the model, view and the presenter be initialized (which is not that big of a problem here, but I can imagine it causing some issues).